# Adding/Removing cell classes with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, cell

I posted a similar question a few hours ago, but I've made a couple breakthroughs(in my mind) and i feel as if I can explain better now.

First off, it's important to say that **all of my images, the ones that I'm trying to edit the classes of, are in cells.** Like, the cells that are within rows that are within a HTML table.

I have a class named .disableMenu, and it's supposed to simply hide the pictures. Here's that class -

```
.disableMenu {
         visibility: hidden;
         }
```

It's simple and it works like a charm. 
So basically, I want a button that when it is pressed, it removes that class from the element(in this case, it's a single cell in a table).

Here's an example of a cell that I'm trying to get this to work on -

```
<table id="table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" align="center">


  <tr >
       <td id="one" >
        <img  src="1.png" class="merge0">
            <script>
                src="js/bootstrap.js"
            </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function changeClass("disableMenu") {
                    var elem = document.getElementById("one");
                    elem.style.class = disableMenu;
                  }
                </script>
       </td>
```

Now, here's the JS button that I'm trying to get to trigger this change of class -

```
<button onclick="changeColor('disableMenu');">GO</button>
```

I'm really sorry for half-double posting this and my general lack of knowledge, but I'm trying to learn(and having fun doing so).

Here's the full code, if anyone wants to have a look -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
   <head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <title>Complete the puzzle!</title>
      <style>
         .disableMenu {
         visibility: hidden;
         }
         .merge {
         position:absolute;
         left: 496px;
         top: 5px;
         }
         .merge0 {
         position:absolute;
         left:300px;
         top:4px;
         }
         .merge1 {
         position:absolute;
         top: 218px;
         left: 530px;

         }
         .merge2 {
         position:absolute;
         top: 218px;
         left: 688px;
         }
         .row1 {
         position:absolute;
         left: 301px;
         top: 208px;
         }
         .row2 {
         position:absolute;
         top: 476px;
         left: 301px;
         margin:0;
         }
         .row3 {
         position:absolute;
         top: 495px;
         left: 716px;
         margin:0;
         }
         .row4 {
         position:absolute;
         top: 691px;
         left: 300px;
         margin:0;
         }
      </style>
   <body style="

      ">

      <div>
         <table id="table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" align="center">
            <tr >
               <td id="one" >
                <img  src="1.png" class="merge0">
                    <script>
                        src="js/bootstrap.js"
                    </script>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function changeClass("disableMenu") {
                            var elem = document.getElementById("one");
                            elem.style.class = disableMenu;
                          }
                        </script>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <img id="2" src="6.png" class="merge">
               </td>
               <td>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <img src="4.png" class="row1">
               </td>
               <td id="gone">
                  <img src="2.png" class="merge1">
               </td>
               <td>
                  <img src="7.png" class="merge2">
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <img src="8.png" class="row2">
               </td>
               <td>
                  <img src="5.png" class="row3">
               </td>
               <td>
                  <img src="3.png" class="row4">
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
      <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
      <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Thanks for looking, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your function declaration is a syntax error. Did you mean `function changeClass(disableMenu /* Notice no quotes */) { var elem = document.getElementById("one"); elem.style.class = disableMenu; }`?

Comment: Also, your function is called `changeClass` but you call `changeColor`.

Comment: `elem.style.class` should be `elem.className`

Comment: Ah, the changeColor thing. Was following a tutorial but then I got confused and left off.
Thanks for all the suggestions, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elem.style.class = disableMenu;
```

This is a big problem. There is not style attribute called "class". You want:

```
elem.className = "disableMenu";
```

and

```
elem.className = "";
```

to disable it.

You're also calling the wrong function:

```
<button onclick="changeColor('disableMenu');">GO</button>
```

should be

```
<button onclick="changeClass('disableMenu');">GO</button>
```

Hope this helps!

===================

Per your comment below I'm fixing your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeClass("disableMenu") {
        var elem = document.getElementById("one");
        elem.className = "disableMenu";
        //I put this line in there so you could UNDO your changes.
        //Calling this immediately after the previous line will just undo what you did.
        //Remove it an you should be good (the line below)
        elem.className = ""; 

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome reply! So I've made the following change to the JS code, now it's this - 

`<script type="text/javascript">
       function changeClass("disableMenu") {
          var elem = document.getElementById("one");
          elem.className = "disableMenu";
          elem.className = "";
        }
                  </script>`

and I changed the button(what a stupid mistake, haha). Unfortunately, nothing happens now, it's the same as it was before in terms of functionality. 

I know I'm missing something here, sorry for my new-ness!

Comment: Its to remove the disabled class. It's equivalent to saying "okay, show the image again". :)

Comment: I was trying to point out the mistake in @Mitchyl code from the comment section; he sets the class attribute and then removes it on the next line

Comment: @Mitchyl did you read your own code? Work with me and try to figure out what the problem is at least a little bit, don't just blindly copy/paste. Anyways, I updated my answer with a fixed version of what you put in the comment. There's a  pretty glaring/obvious error in there.

Comment: @dudewad Just started working again today so I'm looking at it right now. I'm really new at this, so I didn't see the obvious error there(still learning what everything does, haha). 

So if I were to create a button which executed this code, the `elem.classname = "disableMenu";` would add the class, and the `elem.classname = "";` would remove it? So I could have two buttons, one for hiding and one for restoring.

I never thought of it like that, but that's really neat!

Comment: @Mitchyl - Exactly! You're moving in the right direction with adding the class. It's pretty standard (just so you know) to use a class of "hidden" when hiding stuff. If you wanted to get a little more in line with something most coders would expect, you could do that. "disableMenu" could imply that the functionality of the menu is turned off, or something else, and you want to make sure your class names are descriptive of what they're doing! Just some food for thought :)

Comment: @dudewad I think I'm starting to get it now! The only problem I have now, is that the second part(`elem.classname = "";`), didn't appear to work. I had to create a second class, named "enableMenu"(I'll change the classnames later), and needed to use this: `elem.classname = "enableMenu"`. Basically, enableMenu is just a class that says `visibility: visible;`.

Comment: @Mitchyl it might be smart to make 2 functions: show() and hide(). hide() would be the same function you have now; you just change it's name. Then you can copy it, rename it to show(), and use the className = "" there. Also, i noticed that you are using classname = "" and not className = ""; (note the capital "N"). Casing is important otherwise you're trying to reference a different property of the elem object entirely (elem.className is NOT elem.classname)

Comment: @dudewad Ah, yeah. I learned about the casing the hard way, after spending an hour wondering why it just wouldn't work!

I've done what you suggested, which was make two functions. So I've got the first one, which adds the "disableMenu" class to the element. 

Now I have a second function, named differently, copied and pasted exactly the same except I changed the class from "disabledMenu" to "". Unfortunately, the second function doesn't work, it does nothing. 

Thanks for the great help though, you're really helping me to understand this!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58995/discussion-between-dudewad-and-mitchyl).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but building on dudewad's answer -

Try this code to add the class:

```
<table id="table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" align="center">
  <tr >
       <td id="one" >
           <p class="merge0">Hi</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<script>

function myFunction() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("one");
        elem.className = "disableMenu";
}                       
</script>
```